# Objective C: Any existing framework for comment engine?

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks

I am intending to build an iPhone/iPad app that has a feature allowing users to upload their comments. (like facebook comments). Is there any existing framework that I can use to build this?

Appreciate your help on this

Comment: Have you look at the Facebook API?

Comment: Yup I checked, it seems to be more for web apps than mobile apps though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) open source library allows you to integrate Facebook into your iOS application include iPhone, iPad and iPod touch.

Except as otherwise noted, the Facebook iOS SDK is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)